# Ember.js: Move controller computed properties from multiple models into a new model

Tags: ember.js, service, model, controller, json-api

Given a model `substances` containing an attribute `measurements` which is an array with objects. Every object is a measurement with some attributes like `(int) value`.
Second model `elements` is a collection containing global data for all specific elements, such as average values.

I want every measurement to contain the respective element as an attribute, so I can pass it to components. E.g.:

```
{{#each contents as |m|}}
    {{some-graph m}}
    {{some-chart m}}
    {{some-data m}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm doing a single `findAll(elements, {limit: 300, reload: false})` once, so that every substance doesn't do dozens of requests to the jsonapi server. So the model for `route:substance` is:

```
model(params) {
    return {
        substance   : this.store.findRecord('substance', params.substance_id),
        elements    : this.store.findAll('element', {limit: 300, reload: false}})
    }
},
```

I tried combining the two in `model:substance`, but `model:elements` is not available there (for obvious reasons). So I am doing this in `controller:substance` like so:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    substance       : computed.alias('model.substance'),
    measurements    : computed.alias('substance.measurements'),
    elements        : computed.alias('model.elements'),
    contents        : computed('{elements,measurements}.[]', function() {
        if (!this.get('elements')) return null
        if (!this.get('measurements')) return null
        return this.get('measurements').map(m => {
            const element = this.get('elements').find(detail => detail.id == m.id)
            if (element) set(m, 'element', element)
            return m
        })
    }),

    // More calculations w/ `utils` here based on `contents`
```

This works, but there are some problems. First (1), the `contents:computed` fires 3 times.

1. When it is referenced is the template;
2. when `model.substance` is loaded;
3. when `model.elements` is loaded.

Not a big problem (overhead) because the first two times, it will `return null`.

Second (2), all references to a specific measurement in the template (e.g.: `{{contents.oxigen.value}}` ) will literally display `undefined` until everything is calculated in the 3rd `computed` iteration. I would like it to display nothing ('') until it is loaded.

However, my final goal is to be able to pass `substance` (with the combined `measurement`s + `element`s) to a shopping-cart-like `service` so you can compose your own list of substances, after which it can make calculations and show a summary, independent of your current route/controller.

**How do I move these `controller:substance` computations to a self-contained item (model?) that can be passed around to services** (3), given that I cannot do this inside `model:substance`?

I cannot reference this `controller:substance` from a `service`, because controllers are singeltons.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a service with a loadSubstanceContent() function, which you then call in your model hook? This function then could load the substance model, the elements, compute them together and return the result. The service also could cache elements or even the computed results. The service would be also available in components and with caching there won't be a recomputing needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have all data resolved before you display any data, you can use [RSVP.hash](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/functions/rsvp/hash) which will resolve only when both promises have resolved.

```
import { hash } from 'rsvp';
model(params) {
    return hash({
        substance   : this.store.findRecord('substance', params.substance_id),
        elements    : this.store.findAll('element', {limit: 300, reload: false}})
    });
}
```

Now, contents will only be computed once, because the controller won't load until both are resolved.
Measurements can't be undefined because the data has already been loaded.

Comment: +1 for explaining `hash`. This way however, everything still depends on a `controller`. I would like to use the same computed values on different pages (e.g. different controllers).